# Thread-safe collection accessible at the same time by multiple users

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety

I'm developing multiplayer game and I have a server written on `asp.net`. Game users send requests to server to find an oponent and join some kind of battle. Battle request can have some parameters, but it also can possibly have none (and it's estimated to be the most popular scenario), so sender should be connected to any of users that have already sent their requests and wait for connection.

Is storing all waiting requests in a thread-safe collection a good idea? It always will contain quite a few elements (because matches for battle are found very quickly), however, a lot of threads will try to access this collection at a time. And is it a good idea to create different collection for every `N` requests? What is the optimal size of `N`? Or maybe some other ideas? My key issues are finding matches quickly and without damaging server performance, even if number of current connections is very big.

**UPD**

It seems that I've described my issue not very clearly. All battle information - participating users, actions during battle, winner etc., is stored in database. What I need is to process requests to join the battle (request contains only sender id and battle filters, possibly). Generally, opponent will be found almost immediately so there's no need to store request data (it should be removed after match is found, and all battle data will be stored in database), but, however, I must be ready to process great amount of requests at the same time.

Comment: @SLaks should I store request in database just for removing it in few miliseconds when match is found? I ment storing just requests - sender id plus battle filters. All batlle information is, of course, stored in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into criteria for matching players, you should not hold user session data in memory when writing web applications. Your web application can be occasionally recycled causing your to loose data.

As SLaks said, you should store this data in database and make selection from there. You should think about performance optimization from this base line, depending on user matching logic. Either select top n users, or create a query based on desired criteria.

Comment: Maybe I've described my issue not very clearly. All battle information - participating users, actions during battle, winner etc., is stored in database. What I need is to process requests to join the battle (request contain onlu sender id and battle filters). Generally, opponent will be found almost immediately so there's no need to store request data, but, however, I must be ready to process great amount of requests at the same time.

Comment: If matches are made immediately so that there is no danger of failed requests why do you think that using single thread-safe collection can be a problem? A request may fail, you can just decide that it is low enough number that you don't care. As for in-memory data structure, I would attempt to create indexed data structure instead of a flat one. Represent your battle filters as a tree structure (most discriminating filter first), and store players as tree nodes. I don't see what you would get by holding multiple separate collections of game requests.